# Put a text on a NSTextField from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I want to put text in a NSTextField, as if it was a Label.

I have tried the following:

```
[textFieldInstance setStringValue:@"Hello"];
```

Comment: use `[textFieldInstance setText:@"Hello"];`

Comment: setStringValue should work, what is your concern? Text or look?

Answer (score -1):

Adding text to a UITextField?

In Objective-C:

```
myTextField.text = @"Your text here";
```

In Swift:

```
myTextField.text = "Your text here"
```

It's the **text** property of UITextField that controls what characters are displayed.

Please consult the documentation as this can be easily looked up!

Comment: Adding text to a NSTextField

Comment: @MarcosGómez You never said `NSTextField` in your question and you tagged it both iOS and Cocoa. I fixed your question's tags.